# VSCode installation on CentOS6 fails with libsecret dependency

Tags: visual-studio-code

In March 2017, I successfully installed VSCode on CentOS 6. When I try to install it on a clean install of CentOS 6 now, I now get an error running `sudo yum install code`:

```
Error: Package: code-1.17.0-1507160302.el7.x86_64 (code)
       Requires: libsecret-1.so.0()(64bit)
```

Is this a new dependency? Any workarounds for installing VSCode on CentOS now, or can I get to an older build?

Comment: CentOS 6 uses glibc 2.12, while Visual Studio Code requires v2.14 at the minimum. I doubt you'll get it running on that platform, as you can't just install a newer version of glibc - it's the most fundamental library and replacing it might not be impossible in theory, but in practice, using a system with a more modern version (e.g. CentOS 7) will be much easier.

Comment: @ShellZero Is there any reason VS Code can't be built from source on Centos 6? Do you know any what dependency brings in the 2.14 requirement?

Comment: @robince It's as per their design. According to their Requirements here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/requirements#_platforms and  one of the developer on VS Code has answered it here https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/23232

Comment: I thought that is for the binaries they distribute and support (MS branded) - the glibc errors are because it is compiled on a system with newer glibc. I tried to build from source and the problem I ran into was keytar package which requires libsecret. Libsecret is a newer library that replaces gnome-keychain. Centos 6 has the gnome-keychain but no libsecret, and I couldn't find a way to get libsecret installed on centos 6 (or to get vscode to accept an older version of keytar, 3.0.2 is the last that requires gnome-keychain instead of libsecret).

Comment: The best description (lengthy) of the problem and why it's hard to fix: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/02/17/upgrading-the-gnu-c-library-within-red-hat-enterprise-linux/

Answer (score 4):

According to Visual Studio Code Requirements, `GLIBC Version 2.15` or later is required. And `CentOS 6` uses `2.12`. Hence, you cannot build the VS Code on this OS. It's better to use a more modern version like `CentOS 7`.

Please refer to the VS Code requirements [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/requirements#_platforms)

You can also refer to one of the issues on the github repo [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/23232) where the developer on VS Code has mentioned about it.

Hope this helps.